# Android - toolbar at bottom - how to show a border line at the top

Tags: android, android-layout, android-appcompat, android-toolbar

For some screens I use the "android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar" as an **bottom toolbar**. Works great.

I would like to show a thin border at the top. How to create that border? 
Below this border (line) the menu items are shown normally / horizontally.

The toolbar could be as simple as this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_bottom"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

This border should be configurable as part of the toolbar, because on some actions the bottom toolbar is made invisible (and visible again).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a simple view above your toolbar, and the whole thing contained in a same layout so you can control `visibility`. You can customize the view with color, height etc

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:gravity="bottom"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:id="@+id/container">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:id="@+id/view_toolbar" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_bottom"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


</LinearLayout>
```

And in Java :

```
 RelativeLayout container = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
 if(condition...){
       container.setVisibility(View.GONE);
 } else {
       container.setVisibility(View.VISIBILE);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, this will work. Before setting it as THE answer, I will see whether there is an toolbar-inline version possible.

Comment: So did you find something better ?